# Hybrid ionic mobile app: hide login screen after successful login

Tags: android, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing mobile app with ionic framework.it has a side menu with following links

1.Home

1.Login

2.About

3.Settings

When user is logged in i want to change the `login` in side menu to `myprofile` link

In the login controller

```
.controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,$state){
   $scope.login=function(user){
      //http call for login api 
      //set the auth token
      window.localStorage.setItem('usertoken',response.token);
      $state.go('app.profile');
     }
}})
```

In Menu controller

```
.controller('MenuCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

  //shows the login link when the user is not logged in othewise show profile.
  if(window.localStorage.getItem('usertoken')==null){
       $scope.showloginlink=true;
       $scope.showprofilelink=false;
  }else{
      $scope.showloginlink=false;
      $scope.showprofilelink=true;
  }

});
```

Here is htmll

```
<ion-list >
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/login" ng-show="showloginlink">
          Login
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/profile" ng-show="showprofilelink">
          Profile
        </ion-item>
```

The problem it dosen't show the profile link after login,but when i refresh the entire page it will works as i expected
How to solve this problem?

**UPDATE**

I have solved the problem via reload the state

```
$state.go('app.profile',null,{reload: true});
```

But i wil get another error,side menu  is missing from my `user_profilepage`
I've added  this `enable-menu-with-back-views="true"` in `menu.html` ,but still i have the menu missing problem:(

**Note:I am using ionic tabs template**

Comment: Have you tried the $timeout solution? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your assignment with $apply, like this:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  if(window.localStorage.getItem('usertoken')==null){
       $scope.showloginlink=true;
       $scope.showprofilelink=false;
  }else{
      $scope.showloginlink=false;
      $scope.showprofilelink=true;
  }    
});
```

If you get an error to say a digest is already running, swap out $scope.$apply with $timeout, which is a service you'll need to inject. That will defer the update until the next digest if you don't specify a specific delay.

So first inject it into your controller by adding it as a parameter:

```
.controller('LoginCtrl',function($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,$state, $timeout){
```

Then, replace $scope.$apply from the previous listing:

```
$timeout(function() {
  if(window.localStorage.getItem('usertoken')==null){
       $scope.showloginlink=true;
       $scope.showprofilelink=false;
  }else{
      $scope.showloginlink=false;
      $scope.showprofilelink=true;
  }    
});
```

Comment: how to wrap `$scope.apply` in `timeout` ?,i will get digest already running error

Comment: I updated the answer to show a proper example of how to use $timeout.